# Page CSS fails on deployment server

Tags: css, firefox

I have a page which works locally but when deployed, none of he CSS works.  in Firefox I get these errors.  I never used to get this before.  Any idea why this may be happening?

[image]

Also, when viewing the source of the page I can see this

```
<link href="/Content/css/foo.css?v=1.0" rel="stylesheet">
The resource from this URL is not text: http://foo.iat.company.local/Content/css/foo.css?v=1.0
</link>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the paths referencing those files are correct? Those look like 404 errors.

Comment: I guess you have typo somewhere in your code

Comment: Oh yes, hey certainly do.  The code is still the same as it was yesterday and there have been permission changes on the server.

Comment: The errors in your Firebug suggest that what is suppose to be your JS file has a doctype declaration at the top. The server is clearly doing something weird.

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: open the url of one of your css files in firefox and see what it says,  use firebug to get the http response code, then you know whats going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you're showing in console seem to suggest that the first line of your JS files is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which it shouldn't be for JavaScript files!

I suspect that your links to the stylesheets aren't working and it's instead returning a 404 page (the screenshot certainly seems to suggest it's returning a document with HTML in it).

To try and double-check:

- open up the page in Firefox and view source (right-click and 'View
  Source');
- In FireFox source view the assets URLs will be hyperlinks;
- try clicking on the link for one of the JS files and see what gets
  displayed.

I suspect you're going to find it returns you an error page and not the JS you expect!

If that's the case, you need to take another look at your folder structure and try and work out why your markup is pointing at the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Check what your CSS files stored in correct place. Try open URL to CSS in browser. Also check in Firebug in tab Network what files loaded and from what URL. There is similar to your pages tried load CSS files from incorrect URL and got page for 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Content folder didn't have permission that it required.  I added he following users to the security tab of the properties window of the Content folder and set permissions for those users and it all worked fine.

creator owner

iusr

network service

users

iis_usrs